# List Contour Plot: Delete some contour lines, but keep the colors

Tags: plotting, graphics, color

I'm trying to make a `ContourPlot` of a set of data of the kind: $(x,y,f(x,y))$

What I'd like to do is to remove the majority of the iso-line and just leave two of them, but keeping the changing of the color.

In other words I'd like to obtain something like a `ListDensityPlot` of my data set, but with two iso-curves marking the points $(x,y)$ having either value $0$ or $-0.0005$.

Any idea on how to do this?
like for example overlapping two different graphs on each other or extracting the iso-curve interpolant from the contour plot and plug it into the density plot?
these are just some ideas...

Comment: "[`ContourStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourStyle.html) → $\{g_1, g_2, \ldots\}$ specifies that successive directives $g_i$ should be used to draw successive contours." So, for example, `Contours -> {0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5}, ContourStyle -> {Black, None, None, Black}`.

Comment: You could also `Show` a `ListContourPlot` with just the contours you want (and `ContourShading -> None`) on top of a `ListDensityPlot`.

Comment: this seems a very nice idea!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
data = Table[Sin[i + j^2], {i, 0, 3, 0.05}, {j, 0, 3, 0.05}];

ListContourPlot[data, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 Contours -> {{0, {Thick, Black}}, {-.5, {Thick, Dashed, Black}}, 
               Sequence @@ ({#, None} & /@ Range[Min@data, Max@data, .0025])}]
```

[image]

You can also use the desired contours as `Epilog` with `ListDensityPlot`:

```
lcp = ListContourPlot[data, ContourShading -> None,
   Contours -> {{0, {Thick, Black}}, {-.5, {Thick, Dashed, Black}}}];
ListDensityPlot[data, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Epilog -> lcp[[1]]]
```

[image]

Or, to use default contour styles, use `Contours -> {0, -.5}` in `lcp` to get

```
ListDensityPlot[data, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Epilog -> lcp[[1]]]
```

[image]

**Update:** You can also use `Mesh` and `MeshFunctions` with `ListDensityPlot`:

```
ListDensityPlot[data, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", MeshFunctions -> {#3 &},  Mesh -> {{0., -.5}}]
```

[image]