# How to draw a particular contour line in ListDensityPlot?

Tags: plotting

In the plot produced by the following code, I want to draw a contour line for $f(x,y)=0.8$. Here $f(x,y)=\sin(x^2+y)$, however, actually we don't know $f$, we've got the data only.

```
data = Flatten[Table[{x, y, Sin[x^2 + y]}, {x, 0, 1, 0.1}, {y, 0, 1, 0.1}], 1];
ListDensityPlot[data, ImageSize -> Large, PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[Automatic,LegendMargins -> {{0, 0}, {10, 5}}], Right], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, 20]]
```

Comment: `ListDensityPlot[..., MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{0.8}}]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Related Q/A: [ListContourPlot: delete some contour lines, but keep the colors](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/69938/125)

In addition to `Epilog` (Harry's answer) or `MeshFunctions` (rahul's comment) you can also use `ListContourPlot`:

```
ListContourPlot [data, ImageSize -> 400, 
 Contours -> {{0.8, {Thick, Black}}, ##& @@ ({#, None} & /@ Range[Min@data, Max@data, .0025])}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[Automatic, LegendMargins -> {{0, 0}, {10, 5}}], 
   Right], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, 20]]
```

[image]

An alternative way to use `Epilog`:

```
epilog = ListContourPlot [data, Contours -> {{0.8, Thick}}, ContourShading -> None][[1]];
ListDensityPlot[data, ImageSize -> 400, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[Automatic, LegendMargins -> {{0, 0}, {10, 5}}], 
   Right], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, 20], Epilog -> epilog]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

`Epilog` Approach：

```
line = Take[#, 2] & /@Select[Flatten[
Table[{x, y, Sin[x^2 + y]}, {x, 0, 1, 0.01}, {y, 0, 1, 0.01}], 1],
Abs[#[[3]] - 0.8] < 0.002 &]
```

then:

```
data = Flatten[ Table[{x, y, Sin[x^2 + y]}, {x, 0, 1, 0.1}, {y, 0, 1, 0.1}], 1];
density = 
ListDensityPlot[data, ImageSize -> Large, PlotLegends -> 
Placed[BarLegend[Automatic, LegendMargins -> {{0, 0}, {10, 5}}], 
Right], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, LabelStyle ->Directive[Bold, 20], 
Epilog -> {Thick, Blue, Line[line]}]
```

output:
[image]